# Find the vector equation such that set is linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

**Please, only hints and suggestions**

I've tried many things with all fails.

I knew that this set of vectors $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 \}$ is Linearly Independent. So I have to find some vector $v$ such that

$c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3 + c_4v = 0$ but one of them isn't 0.

Comment: Why do you think that v1,v2,v3 is linear dependent?

Comment: Can you solve the equation for $v$?

Comment: @benji, like $v = \frac{c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3}{c_4}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v=[a\;b\;c\;d]^T$ and consider Gaussian elimination on the matrix
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
-1 & 1 & -2 & b\\
0 & 1 & -2 & c\\
2 & 0 & 2 & d
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & 1 & -1 & b+a\\
0 & 1 & -2 & c\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d-2a
\end{bmatrix}
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & 1 & -1 & b+a\\
0 & 0 & -1 & c-b-a\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d-2a
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Thus you see that the vector should satisfy $d=2a$, which is the condition for the linear system
$$
c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3+c_4v=0
$$
to have a non trivial solution.

Comment: very fast. keep it going.

Comment: I am having some trouble. We solve $c_1v_2 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3 + c_4v_4$? Using Augmented matrices?

Comment: Also, you didnt complete the RREF? Is it valid still?

Comment: @Amad27 At that stage, we already know what the pivot columns are, the RREF wold just tell us how to write the vector $v$ as a linear combination of the three vectors (provided $ d=2a$). We're essentially solving $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3$.

Comment: @egreg, also is this matrix augmented? Is the augmented second part $[a, b, c, d]$?

Comment: @Amad27 You can see it as an augmented matrix, if you deem so.

Comment: @egreg, is this another way to see it: You are solving such that $v$ is a linear combination of $v1, v_2, v_3$. So you are solving $c_1 v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3 = v$?

Comment: @Amad27 Yes, that can be an interpretation as good as “find the dimension of the span of $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v\}$.